# Leaflet - How to show Markers instead of Polylines

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polyline

I currently have a set of nicely declared array of latitude/longitude points using javascript and mySQL and when I used this set of arrays to show as polylines it was successful.

var polyline= L.polyline(xxx).addTo(map);

However when I tired to change to markers, the map did not portrayed any markers.

Any help? Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `L.Polyline`, takes a nested array of multiple lat/lng coordinates as the first parameter, `L.Marker` takes a single array with lat/lng coordinates. The signature is different:

L.Polyline:

```
new L.Polyline([[-45, -45], [45, 45]], {/*options*/});
```

L.Marker:

```
new Marker([-45, -45], {/*options*/});
```

When you pass a nested array to `L.Marker`, like the one shown above in the polyline, it throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null

If you want to use the set of coordinates of the polyline to show markers at the start and/or endpoint of the line you could do this:

```
var coordinates = [[-45, -45], [45, 45]];

var startMarker = new Marker(coordinates[0], {/*options*/});
var endMarker = new Marker(coordinates[1], {/*options*/});
```

As promised in the comments another easier way to add markers from a large array:

```
var coordinates = [
  [-41.31825,174.80768],
  [-41.31606,174.80774],
  [-41.31581,174.80777],
  [-41.31115,174.80827],
  [-41.30928,174.80835],
  [-41.29127,174.83841],
  [-41.33571,174.84846],
  [-41.34268,174.82877]
];

coordinates.forEach(function (coordinate) {
  new L.Marker(coordinate).addTo(map);
});
```

Much easier than doing:

```
new L.Marker(coordinate[0]).addTo(map);
new L.Marker(coordinate[1]).addTo(map);
new L.Marker(coordinate[2]).addTo(map);
new L.Marker(coordinate[3]).addTo(map);
new L.Marker(coordinate[4]).addTo(map);
new L.Marker(coordinate[5]).addTo(map);
new L.Marker(coordinate[6]).addTo(map);
new L.Marker(coordinate[7]).addTo(map);
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3dbJgb?p=preview

Comment: Dear @iH8, thank you for your reply, I have a set of coordinates, is your codes still applicable? Really appreciate your help.


`var planelatlong = [
[-41.31825,174.80768],
[-41.31606,174.80774],
[-41.31581,174.80777],
[-41.31115,174.80827],
[-41.30928,174.80835],
[-41.29127,174.83841],
[-41.33571,174.84846],
[-41.34268,174.82877]];`